# Numeros Primos usando Threads Em Python

Tags: python

bom preciso criar um programa em python usando threads que encontre a maior quantidade de numeros primos em 60 segundos, porém nao consigo entender o uso das threads para ele:`

```
import time
import math




def is_prime(number):
    number = int(number)
    if number == 2:
        return True
    num_sqrt = int(math.sqrt(number))
    if number:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            return False
        for i in range(3, num_sqrt+1, 2):
            if number % i == 0:
                return False

    return True

def func_Prime(i):
    i = 0
    numero = 3
    print 'PROGRAMA QUE VERIFICA E MOSTRA QUAIS OS NÚMEROS PRIMOS.'
    ini = time.time()
    final = 0
    while(final < 1):

        numero = numero+1
        resposta = is_prime(numero)
        if resposta:

            i = i+1
            primo = numero
            fim = time.time()
            final = fim - ini
    return primo, i
```

Comment: Fiz uns testes aqui, e mudei algumas coisas na sua função, agora ela esta retornando a quantidade de números primos dado um tempo como parâmetro e ela também retorna o ultimo numero primo. Não sei exatamente o que vc quer, porque vc precisa comparar os valores, mais como sua função retorna muitos números primos fica difícil verificar um por um, então eu assumi como base o ultimo numero retornado por ela verificando se ele e primo.

Comment: O `time` serve para mediar o tempo de execução, neste caso ele esta sendo aplicado para determinar por quanto tempo a função ira ficar calculando numero primo.

Comment: a função desse trabalho e utilização das threads para encontar o maior numero possivel de numeros primos, o codigo retorna o ultimo numero primo encontrado e a quantidade encontrada em 60 segundos

Comment: O `time.time()` não é uma thread se eu não me engano, tem que consultar a documentação.

Comment: Estou confuso sobre o que vc quer e qual é seu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que o indivíduo pretende correr duas funcionalidades ao mesmo tempo. Ou seja, contar todos os números que são primos em 60 s. Enquanto o programa faz a contagem de números primos de 2 até x, faz também a contagem do tempo limitado por 60 s. Quando o tempo atinge 60 s o contador de primos pára. Também procuro como usar threads.

** Era suposto ser um comentário. Peço desculpa. Estou no telemóvel. **

Comment: Para usar uma thread tem de importar o modulo threading